# How to Generate API Token Using Requests

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I'm trying to make API requests to a [local real estate website](https://developer.domain.com.au/docs/read/Authorization)

I need to obtain an oauth2 token then use that to make requests. Unfortunately I am, getting a 400 error when  running the below code. I'm assuming the request url is incorrect but cannot seem to get it. Thanks

```
import requests
import json

token_url = "https://auth.domain.com.au/v1/connect/token"
client_id = '<client_id>'
client_secret = '<client_secret>'
data = {'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=api_agencies_read%20api_listings_read'}

access_token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=data, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, auth=(client_id, client_secret))

print(access_token_response)
```

EDIT:

Changed data to a dictionary as per @aydow comments and changed the 'scope'. I see the API docs ask for the client_id and client_secret to be base64 encoded. Updated code and it now works as it should

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

token_url = "https://auth.domain.com.au/v1/connect/token"
client_id = '<client_id>'
client_secret = '<client_secret>'
payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials','scope': 'api_agencies_read%20api_listings_read'}
headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}


access_token_response = requests.post(token_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret), data=payload, headers=headers)

print(access_token_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request), you can see that `data` needs to be a `dict`. You have it as a `set` containing a string.

Try

```
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'scope': 'api_agencies_read%20api_listings_read'
}
```

Comment: Have changed to a dictionary but am still getting the same error. I see the client requires to be base64 encoded as per the API docs. I believe I have done that but am still getting 400 error