# Getting a error while sending POST method to the API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest

I've been trying to implement this Basic Auth without success because even though this REST API for authentication does not require other parameters other than username and password, I'm getting:

```
{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'Missing grant type'}
```

Here's the API on Postman:

[image]

It returns an acccess_tolken, a token_type and expires_in.

I noticed that on Postman if I only mark the grant_type, it'll still get a response.

[image]

This is the code I'm currently trying to run and getting errors:

```
import requests
import json
  
url = 'https://api-gateway.com/oauth/token'
  
username = "username"
password = "password"
  
response = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password))
  
data = response.json()
  
print(data)
```

What am I doing wrong ? I've been quite confused with this.

Thank you!

Comment: The error seems to suggest you're not sending the grant type in your POST. The Python code sends no body.

Comment: As the error message says, you didn't send the grant type in your code. Something like this might work:
`payload = {'grant_type': 'client'}` 
\
`response = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), data=payload)`
More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412854/how-to-generate-api-token-using-requests

Comment: Did you try to export your Postman request as Python code?

Comment: @SimonUnderwood It worked! Now I have to figure it out how to retrieve the generated token and use it for the next API. Thank you!